# how to know the location of ubuntu installed in vmware in windows 10?

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

*I installed ubuntu in vmware, in windows 10. i want to copy some stuff from windows10 to ubuntu, to use it inside ubuntu. But i am not getting location of ubuntu installed in vmware.*

**so how can i know location of myfiles in ubuntu installed on windows10 ?
i Searched inside Vmware folder in programfiles but had not got ubuntu folder and files**

Answer (score 0):

The files of your vmware guest are not directly accessible from your host.

You have to set up file sharing or use a shared folder.

See: [Sharing Files Between Guest and Host Operating Systems](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html)